# Create android emulator(avd) with custom screen size and resolution from command line

Tags: java, android, emulation

I have to create an android emulator from command line in windows with below specifications,

```
screen size --> 4.7 inch
screen resolution --> 540x960 pixels
android version --> 4.4.2
```

i trying to create this emualtor from java.

i tried with

```
android -create avd -n <device_name> -t <apilevel> -c 300M -f
```

but it does create the emulator with screen size? what is the option and how can we create avd with custom screen size?

Answer (score 3):

Android [Official doc : Customize the device resolution or density](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html)

> Use the create avd command to create a new AVD, specifying the --skin option with a value that references either a default skin name (such as "WVGA800") or a custom skin resolution (such as 240x432). Here's an example:

1. `android create avd -n <name> -t <targetID> --skin WVGA800`
   **OR**
2. `android create avd -n <name> -t <targetID> --skin 540x960`

**UPDATED**
    This tool is no longer supported. Instead use Android Studio to [create AVDs](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, the android command is deprecated. And the new avdmanager doesn't support --skin

Answer (score 1):

I know, it's old, but maybe I can help others:

I am using linux, the directories may be different in windows or in custom installations.

1. Create your standard VDI (./avdmanager create avd -n <name_vdi> -d <id_template>)
2. Go to directory /home/<user_dir>/.android/avd/<name_vdi>
3. Edit the file config.ini, search the following lines and change theirs values as you want:

`hw.lcd.height=2340`

`hw.lcd.width=1080`

4. Save it and run your emulator again.

I hope I can help you or another person with the same issue.

Comment: That doesn't seem to have much effect. My values for these fields were already set to my display size but the emulator is still much smaller than my screen.